# Python - multiply dictionary values for a list and store the result back in a different dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, data-science, equation

I have this problem: two dictionaries, one "dicT" and the other "dictionary". I want to multiply "dicT" for a list (listT) and store the result back in a dictionary, with keys from dicT. Any ideas?

I thought to do the following:

```
    for i in dPdT:
        for value in dicT.values():
            if not i in dictionary:
                dictionary[i] = []
            dictionary[i].append(i*value)
```

But it ends up in the following traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "isochore.py", line 197, in <module>
    main()
  File "isochore.py", line 164, in main
    dictionary[i].append(i*value)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you give an example of the data and what you expect it to do? What do you expect when you multiply i * value while you think i is also a key so perhaps alphanumeric? That is also the errorcode you are getting.

I tried to guess, please provide actual data because I don't understand what you are trying to do? This is providing all the values in list l multiplied with that value of l so basically **2 ?

```
oldDictionary = {1: 10,2: 20}
L =[0, 2]
newDictionary = {}

for i in L:
    if i in oldDictionary:
        newDictionary.update({i: oldDictionary.get(i) * i})

print(newDictionary)
```

```
{2: 40}
```

Comment: Actually, I can multiply with the logic I described. However, the result is not as I expected.             newDictionary = {}
        for i in List:
            for key, value in oldDictionary.items():
                for j in key:
                    if not i in newDictionary:
                        newDictionary[i] = []
                    newDictionary[i].append(i * j)

Comment: The logic I'm trying to implement is: "dictionaryY n-th term = ListZ m-th term * dictionaryX n-th term"